# Would a celestial cryptographic system be useful in practice?

Tags: encryption

I [posted a question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/93804/could-celestial-objects-be-used-in-cryptography) recently about whether a celestial body could be used in cryptography. I got many fantastic responses explaining how the celestial object could be used to generate a common reference string.

My follow up question is then: if it were possible and feasible to use a celestial object to allow two parties to communicate securely, would this only be of academic interest perhaps for government agencies? Or could it have advantages that would be more generally desirable for cryptography either now or in the future?

Comment: Do you want to disregard the obvious & huge drawbacks - such as clouds - of doing so?

Comment: There is plenty of information you can get from astronomical objects which is not affected by clouds or the atmosphere. The practicalities are discussed in my other post, here I am more interested in whether there would be a need / demand for such a system *with the assumption* that the system works.

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you mean _"pactice"_, or _"physically possible?"_ I ask as you can get 10's kBits/hr out of the old `\dev\random` (yes the one without the `u`).